# Using ruby and aws-sdk to pull ec2 tags

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Folks,
  I am trying to pull in the EC2 tags via ruby aws-sdk and iam roles.  The following bit of code produces error below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'fileutils'

ec2 = AWS::EC2.new()

instance_id = `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
outdir = '/opt/facts/tags/'

unless File.directory?(outdir)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(outdir)
end

ec2= AWS::EC2.new()
instance = ec2.instances[instance_id]
tags = instance.tags

tags.each do |num|
  File.open(outdir+num[0], "w") do |f|
    f.write(num[1])
  end
end
```

Following output:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/http/connection_pool.rb:127:in `session_for': undefined method `continue_timeout=' for #<Net::HTTP ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 open=false> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/http/net_http_handler.rb:52:in `handle'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:236:in `make_sync_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:262:in `retry_server_errors'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:229:in `make_sync_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:489:in `client_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:371:in `log_client_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:457:in `client_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:353:in `return_or_raise'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:456:in `client_request'
from (eval):3:in `describe_tags'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/ec2/filtered_collection.rb:44:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/ec2/filtered_collection.rb:44:in `filtered_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-sdk-1.9.0/lib/aws/ec2/resource_tag_collection.rb:156:in `each'
from ./puppetclient.rb:22
```

Comment: bug in aws-sdk :)  fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a bug that was already reported today:  [undefined method `continue_timeout='](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/232), you could try pointing to the main branch of the git repository since there's  already a patch for it.

**Edit:**

You can already point the latest version in `rubygems` since they already deployed the fix on `version 1.9.1`:
https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk

Comment: @Clustermagnet I don't get it, that link doesn't seems to have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug announced today in AWS-SDK-ruby https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/232

You can fix it by updating your gemfile

```
gem 'aws-sdk', "1.9.1"
```

And then running "bundle"